# Whta's difference between web3.utils.toHex() and web3.utils.keccak256()?

Tags: solidity, web3js, keccak, hex

I've been practicing Ethernaut CTF and I'm stuck on the [Delegation problem](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493).

First, I tried to approach this in the console. But I couldn't get ownership.

```js
var pwn = web3.utils.toHex("pwn()")
await contract.sendTransaction({data: pwn})
```

Second, I tried different approach. And finally, I got ownership.

```js
var pwn_function = web3.utils.keccak256("pwn()")
await contract.sendTransaction({data: pwn_function})
```

By the way, What's the difference between the first approach and the second one?
And I could find `web3.utils.toHex` in the web3.js document but couldn't find `web3.utils.keccak256`. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `toHex` and `keccak256` are very different things.

The first simply converts something (usually a number) to hexadecimal format. So it's basically encoding the data differently, but the data is still exactly the same - you can convert it back if you want to.

The second is calculating a hash value for the given data. You can't reverse that operation: you can't get the input from the output.

I don't know why the `keccak256` function can't be found by searching in the web3js documentation (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/search.html?q=keccak256&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3

Comment: I know that the data field must have hexadecimal numbers, but aren't both `toHex` and `keccak256` making hexadecimal numbers? By the way, why can I get ownership only for the value that came out as `keccak256`?

Comment: Hexadecimal format is just a way to represent data. Yes, those both happen to output their data in hex format. No idea about why you need to use `keccak256`, you can post a new question about that if you wish.